VLSM NETWORKING - Solving for the Network ID and the number of hosts in each VLANs
This is completely a new set of problem for me in which I do not know the answer to. I am having trouble in solving for "X". Could someone please guide me in how to identify the IP address?
IP ADD: (15+X).75.18.19 /13
VLANs:
61 = 499 + X hosts
62 = 14405 hosts
63 = 52 + X hosts
64 = 32717 + X hosts
65 = 909 hosts
66 = 8 hosts
LANs:
1 = 118 + X hosts
2 = 2006 + X hosts
WAN:
50 + X hosts

I tried to compute for X by:
14405 + 909 + 8 + 499 + 52 + 32717 + 118 + 2006 + 50 + 6X = 50764 + 6X
Since the total available IP addresses are 524,288 (/13 subnet),
6X = 524,288 − 50,764
6X = 473,524
Then, divide by 6:
X = 78,921
To get the first Octet (Network ID),
78,921 % 256 = 89
15 + 89 = 104
Therefore the IP Address is 104.75.18.19/13
I am still unsure as to whether this is correct since most of this came from chatGPT. I'm asking for a verification if this is correct.

VLSM is an obsolete term from the classful networking era, more than 30 years ago. It's CIDR since.
